# Confusion about Intent and intent_filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

While reading about [intent resolution](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Resolution) I got these lines for action test:

> To pass this filter, the action specified in the Intent must match one
>   of the actions listed in the filter.
>
> If the filter does not list any actions, there is nothing for an
>   intent to match, so all intents fail the test. However, if an Intent
>   does not specify an action, it passes the test as long as the filter
>   contains at least one action.

My confusion is that how can it pass the test if intent_filter has one action and intent doesn't specify any action. Because to pass the test the intent must contain at least one of the actions included in intent_filter.

Am I understanding wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

> However, if an Intent does not specify an action, it passes the test as long as the filter contains at least one action.

This special case is documented because it is a special case. This allows us to not specify an action but specify other parameters of the Intent in order to launch an Activity or Service.

Comment: But its also saying that "as long as the filter contains at least one action". So, intent_filter will contain an action and intent won't specify any action. How will that works, as at least one action needs to match?